# Como usar o pdo no php fazendo herança via composição?

Tags: php, herança, composição

Não consigo mem pensar na estrutura correta para criar aplicativo em composição no PHP.

A principio tenho as classes Pessoa e Aluno.
A classe Aluno instancia a classe Pessoa a fim de usar seus atributos e métodos é claro. Caracterizando uma herança por composição.
Obs.: sempre fiz herança direta com o uso do extends, mas quero mudar isso isolando melhor as classes.

Mas to perdido no meio de alguns erros.

- Na classe Pessoa tento fazer um select genérico que será usado na classe Aluno, contudo tenho erros no que parece ser a instanciação da classe Connection.

O que eu quero alem de entender a estrutura é usar corretamente o modelo de composição.

Usando eclipse + MySQL + Apache

segue código:

CLASSE PESSOA

```
<?php
namespace site\modulo1;


include_once 'init.php';

class Pessoa
{
    private $cpf;
    private $rg;
    private $nome;
    private $data_nascimento;
    private $endereco;
    private $bairro;
    private $cidade;
    private $estado;
    private $pais;
    private $cep;



    function setPessoa( $cpf, $rg, $nome, $data_nascimento, $endereco, 
    $bairro,$cidade, $estado, $pais, $cep){

        $this->cpf= $cpf;
        $this->rg = $rg;
        $this->nome = $nome;
        $this->data_nascimento = $data_nascimento;
        $this->endereco = $endereco;
        $this->bairro = $bairro;
        $this->cidade = $cidade;
        $this->estado = $estado;
        $this->pais = $pais;
        $this->cep = $cep;

    }
    function getPessoa($table){

        $sql = "SELECT cpf, rg, nome, data_nascimento, endereco, 
bairro,cidade, estado, pais, cep FROM $table";
        $q='';
        $q->exec(sql);


    foreach ($q as $row) {

        $data[]=$q;
    }

    return $data;
  //  $connexao->closeConnection();
}

function postPessoa($table){

    $dados = array($this->cpf, $this->rg, $this->nome, $this->data_nascimento, $this->endereco, $this->bairro, $this->cidade, $this->estado, $this->pais,  $this->cep);

    $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO $table (cpf, rg, nome, data_nascimento, endereco, bairro,cidade, estado, pais, cep) 
            VALUES (:cpf, :rg, :nome, :data_nascimento, :endereco, :bairro,:cidade, :estado, :pais, :cep)")->execute($dados);                                               
    unset($conn);
}


function updatePessoa($table){

}

function deletePessoa($table){

}

}
```

CLASSE ALUNO

```
<?php
namespace site;

use site\modulo1\Pessoa;



include_once 'site/modulo1/Pessoa.php';



class Aluno
{
    private $matricula;
    private $Pessoa;

    function __construct() {

       $this->Pessoa = new Pessoa();

    }

    public function setAluno( $cpf, $rg, $nome, $data_nascimento, 
$endereco, $bairro,$cidade, $estado, $pais, $cep){

        $this->Pessoa->setPessoa($cpf, $rg, $nome, $data_nascimento, 
 $endereco, $bairro, $cidade, $estado, $pais, $cep);
    }


    public function postAluno(){

        $this->Pessoa->postPessoa();

    }

public function listaAlunos(){

   $this->Pessoa->getPessoa('alunos');

}
/**
     * @return mixed
    */
    public function getMatricula()
    {
        return $this->matricula;
    }

/**
     * @return \site\modulo1\Pessoa
     */
    public function getPessoa()
     {
        return $this->Pessoa;
    }

/**
     * @param mixed $matricula
     */
    public function setMatricula($matricula)
    {
        $this->matricula = $matricula;
    }

 /**
     * @param \site\modulo1\Pessoa $Pessoa
     */
    public function setPessoa($Pessoa)
    {
        $this->Pessoa = $Pessoa;
    }


}
?>
<div class="panel panel-warning">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3>Listando Alunos</h3>
    </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
        <a href="index.php?pagina=site_modulo1_Aluno" class="btn btn-
primary"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"> </span> Novo 
   Aluno</a>
        <br><br>
        <table class="listagem table table-bordered table-striped 
table-responsive">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>matricula</th>
                    <th>cpf</th>
                    <th>rg</th>
                    <th>nome</th>
                    <th>data nascimento</th>
                    <th>endereco<th>
                    <th>bairro</th>
                    <th>cidade</th>
                    <th>estado</th>
                    <th>pais</th>
                    <th>cep</th>
                    <th width="90px">Editar</th>
                    <th width="90px">Excluir</th>
                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php $Aluno = new Pessoa();
                    $Aluno->getPessoa('alunos');
                  Foreach ($results as $Aluno) { ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><b><?php echo $Aluno->getMatricula();?></b></td>
                    <td><?php echo $Aluno->getCpf();?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $Aluno->getRG() ?></td>
                    <td><a href="index.php?pagina=estados_editar&id=<?php echo $Aluno->getMatricula;?>">Editar</a></td>
                    <td><a href="index.php?pagina=estados_excluir&id=<?php echo $Aluno->getMatricula;?>">Excluir</a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="5" class="text-center"><?php echo date('d/m/Y h:i:s'); ?></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

CLASSE CONEXÃO

```
<?php
namespace site;

use site\modulo1\Pessoa;

include_once 'site/modulo1/Pessoa.php';


   /**
     * @author developer Fabiano
      * 
    * relação de composição com classe Pessoa;
    */
   class Aluno
  {
      private $matricula;
      private $Pessoa;

     function __construct() {

     $this->Pessoa = new Pessoa();

  }

public function setAluno( $cpf, $rg, $nome, $data_nascimento, $endereco, $bairro,$cidade, $estado, $pais, $cep){

    $this->Pessoa->setPessoa($cpf, $rg, $nome, $data_nascimento, $endereco, $bairro, $cidade, $estado, $pais, $cep);
}


public function postAluno(){

    $this->Pessoa->postPessoa();

}

public function listaAlunos(){

   $this->Pessoa->getPessoa('alunos');

}

GETTERS AND SETERS

}
?>
```

Comment: Sinceramente, não vejo motivos para fazer isso. Herança e composição são coisas distintas, não? E não vejo porque utilizar a composição aqui. Um aluno é composto de uma pessoa? Não faz sentido. Um aluno é uma pessoa, então o correto seria herança, não composição. Forçar a composição neste caso faz que o código não faça sentido semanticamente. Se quer usar corretamente, use herança, não composição.

Comment: Correto. Acredito que deva usar o método de composição com outro senário. na verdade tenho o programa com herança já feito. Queria aprender a criar com composição pois tenho dificuldade de usar esse método. E composição é diferente mesmo de herança, me expressei mal.

Comment: Posso misturar os métodos? A parte da herança de Pessoa tudo bem é herança. Mas as outras classes do programa onde "couber" uma composição, tenho a liberdade de codificar como composição ou até mesmo agregação se for o caso. Sei que no modelador de banco de dados posso faze-lo. Me parece correto, não?

Comment: Sim, pode fazê-lo. Por exemplo, a classe Carro pode estender a classe Veículo com herança e ter como composição a classe Roda. Se todo Veículo possuir rodas, até esta classe pode utilizar tal composição.

Comment: Ótimo vou proceder assim. obrigado.